# How to express the given function as a factor $e^{7 i x}$ times a real function?

Tags: functions, simplifying-expressions, parametric-functions, factorization, multivalued

I have the function $f(x,b,t,m)$ for $\{x>0,t,b\}$ all reals and $m=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$. For each particular $m\in\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$, I see that $f(x,b,t,m)$ has a multiplicative factor $e^{7 i x}$ times another real function, for example, for $m=1$, we have

$$e^{7 i x} \left(\cos 7 b+\cos t+448 \cos 5 x+128 \cos 7 x+14 \cos x)(251-342 \sin \frac{\pi }{14}+326 \sin \frac{3 \pi }{14}-346 \cos \frac{\pi }{7})-112 \cos 3 x(17 \sin \frac{\pi }{14}-16 (1+\sin \frac{3 \pi }{14})+17 \cos \frac{\pi }{7})\right)$$

> I want to get a similar result for the general $m$; in other words, to show that $f(x,b,t,m)$ can be expressed in terms of this multiplicative factor $e^{7 i x}$ times another real function which is $m$ dependent.

```
f[x_,b_,t_,m_]:=64 + 336 E^(2 I x) + 1008 E^(4 I x) + 1757 E^(6 I x) + 
 1757 E^(8 I x) + 1008 E^(10 I x) + 336 E^(12 I x) + 64 E^(14 I x) + 
 E^(7 I x) Cos[7 b] + 
 8 E^(2 I x) (24 + 110 E^(2 I x) + 215 E^(4 I x) + 215 E^(6 I x) + 
    110 E^(8 I x) + 12 E^(10 I x)) Cos[(2 m \[Pi])/7] + 
 4 E^(2 I x) (40 + 202 E^(2 I x) + 201 E^(4 I x) + 201 E^(6 I x) + 
    202 E^(8 I x) + 40 E^(10 I x)) Cos[(4 m \[Pi])/7] + 
 4 E^(2 I x) (32 + 82 E^(2 I x) + 335 E^(4 I x) + 335 E^(6 I x) + 
    82 E^(8 I x) + 32 E^(10 I x)) Cos[(6 m \[Pi])/7] + 
 2 E^(2 I x) (48 + 128 E^(2 I x) + 527 E^(4 I x) + 527 E^(6 I x) + 
    128 E^(8 I x) + 48 E^(10 I x)) Cos[(8 m \[Pi])/7] + 
 2 E^(2 I x) (32 + 176 E^(2 I x) + 183 E^(4 I x) + 183 E^(6 I x) + 
    176 E^(8 I x) + 32 E^(10 I x)) Cos[(10 m \[Pi])/7] + 
 4 E^(2 I x) (8 + 50 E^(2 I x) + 111 E^(4 I x) + 111 E^(6 I x) + 
    50 E^(8 I x) + 32 E^(10 I x)) Cos[(12 m \[Pi])/7] + 
 2 E^(4 I x) (20 + 59 E^(2 I x) + 59 E^(4 I x) + 20 E^(6 I x)) Cos[(
   16 m \[Pi])/7] + 
 2 E^(4 I x) (8 + 13 E^(2 I x) + 13 E^(4 I x) + 8 E^(6 I x)) Cos[(
   18 m \[Pi])/7] + 
 8 E^(4 I x) (74 + 3 E^(2 I x) + 3 E^(4 I x) + 74 E^(6 I x)) Cos[(
   20 m \[Pi])/7] + 4 E^(6 I x) (1 + E^(2 I x)) Cos[(22 m \[Pi])/7] + 
 1198 E^(6 I x) (1 + E^(2 I x)) Cos[(24 m \[Pi])/7] + 
 E^(7 I x) Cos[t] - 96 I E^(12 I x) Sin[(2 m \[Pi])/7] - 
 804 I E^(6 I x) (1 + E^(2 I x)) Sin[(4 m \[Pi])/7] + 
 328 I E^(4 I x) (1 + E^(6 I x)) Sin[(6 m \[Pi])/7] - 
 256 I E^(4 I x) (1 + E^(6 I x)) Sin[(8 m \[Pi])/7] + 
 366 I E^(6 I x) (1 + E^(2 I x)) Sin[(10 m \[Pi])/7] - 
 96 I E^(12 I x) Sin[(12 m \[Pi])/7] - 
 26 I E^(6 I x) (1 + E^(2 I x)) Sin[(18 m \[Pi])/7] - 
 584 I E^(4 I x) (1 + E^(6 I x)) Sin[(20 m \[Pi])/7] - 
 1196 I E^(6 I x) (1 + E^(2 I x)) Sin[(24 m \[Pi])/7]
```

Comment: Sounds like you want $f(x,b,t,m)/e^{7 i x}$, since the function is $e^{7 i x}$ times this factor; but you probably mean something else.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks for your comment. No, the problem is exactly this; I want to show that for a general $m$, the function $f(x,b,t,m)$ has (as it must) this coefficient $e^{7ix}$. I tried FullSimplify for the general case, but maybe my computer is slow and it takes a lot of time. I thought maybe there is a simple way to simplify the function.

Comment: But it seems to be what I said then, no? For instance `f[x, b, t, m]/E^(7 I x) // ReIm // ComplexExpand // {1, I}.Simplify[#, m \[Element] Integers && 1 <= m <= 6] &`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

f[x_, b_, t_, m_] := 
  64 + 336 E^(2 I x) + 1008 E^(4 I x) + 1757 E^(6 I x) + 1757 E^(8 I x) + 
   1008 E^(10 I x) + 336 E^(12 I x) + 64 E^(14 I x) + E^(7 I x) Cos[7 b] + 
   8 E^(2 I x) (24 + 110 E^(2 I x) + 215 E^(4 I x) + 215 E^(6 I x) + 
      110 E^(8 I x) + 12 E^(10 I x)) Cos[(2 m π)/7] + 
   4 E^(2 I x) (40 + 202 E^(2 I x) + 201 E^(4 I x) + 201 E^(6 I x) + 
      202 E^(8 I x) + 40 E^(10 I x)) Cos[(4 m π)/7] + 
   4 E^(2 I x) (32 + 82 E^(2 I x) + 335 E^(4 I x) + 335 E^(6 I x) + 
      82 E^(8 I x) + 32 E^(10 I x)) Cos[(6 m π)/7] + 
   2 E^(2 I x) (48 + 128 E^(2 I x) + 527 E^(4 I x) + 527 E^(6 I x) + 
      128 E^(8 I x) + 48 E^(10 I x)) Cos[(8 m π)/7] + 
   2 E^(2 I x) (32 + 176 E^(2 I x) + 183 E^(4 I x) + 183 E^(6 I x) + 
      176 E^(8 I x) + 32 E^(10 I x)) Cos[(10 m π)/7] + 
   4 E^(2 I x) (8 + 50 E^(2 I x) + 111 E^(4 I x) + 111 E^(6 I x) + 
      50 E^(8 I x) + 32 E^(10 I x)) Cos[(12 m π)/7] + 
   2 E^(4 I x) (20 + 59 E^(2 I x) + 59 E^(4 I x) + 
      20 E^(6 I x)) Cos[(16 m π)/7] + 
   2 E^(4 I x) (8 + 13 E^(2 I x) + 13 E^(4 I x) + 
      8 E^(6 I x)) Cos[(18 m π)/7] + 
   8 E^(4 I x) (74 + 3 E^(2 I x) + 3 E^(4 I x) + 
      74 E^(6 I x)) Cos[(20 m π)/7] + 
   4 E^(6 I x) (1 + E^(2 I x)) Cos[(22 m π)/7] + 
   1198 E^(6 I x) (1 + E^(2 I x)) Cos[(24 m π)/7] + E^(7 I x) Cos[t] - 
   96 I E^(12 I x) Sin[(2 m π)/7] - 
   804 I E^(6 I x) (1 + E^(2 I x)) Sin[(4 m π)/7] + 
   328 I E^(4 I x) (1 + E^(6 I x)) Sin[(6 m π)/7] - 
   256 I E^(4 I x) (1 + E^(6 I x)) Sin[(8 m π)/7] + 
   366 I E^(6 I x) (1 + E^(2 I x)) Sin[(10 m π)/7] - 
   96 I E^(12 I x) Sin[(12 m π)/7] - 
   26 I E^(6 I x) (1 + E^(2 I x)) Sin[(18 m π)/7] - 
   584 I E^(4 I x) (1 + E^(6 I x)) Sin[(20 m π)/7] - 
   1196 I E^(6 I x) (1 + E^(2 I x)) Sin[(24 m π)/7];
```

Restructuring `f`

```
(expr = f[x, b, t, m] // ComplexExpand // Simplify) // Short[#, 2] &
```

[image]

The initial factor of `expr` is `E^(7*I*x)`

```
(expr2 = ReplacePart[expr, 1 -> TrigToExp[expr[[1]]]]) // Short
```

[image]

Verifying that `expr2` is equivalent to `f[x, b, t, m]`

```
f[x, b, t, m] == expr2 // Simplify

(* True *)
```

Comment: Thanks. I need the complete form of the function in your brackets (which should be $m$ dependent); can we obtain it?

Comment: The expressions are complete. `Short` is used to suppress their full display (note that the parentheses are used to isolate the `Short` from the expressions definitions). Remove each `Short` and you will see the full expressions.